# PHP Getting All Array Values in For Each Loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, import

Ok so I have the following code getting json results from an API:

```
$userGuid = "2d7c4ca4-d1b6-4c2a-9106-33df1251d946";
$apiKey = "my_key";

function query($connectorGuid, $input, $userGuid, $apiKey, $additionalInput) {

  $url = "https://api.import.io/store/connector/" . $connectorGuid . "/_query?_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=" . urlencode($apiKey);

  $data = array("input" => $input);
  if ($additionalInput) {
    $data["additionalInput"] = $additionalInput;
  }

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return json_decode($result, true);
}

// Query for tile Bundesliga Stats
$result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
  "webpage/url" => "http://msn.foxsports.com/foxsoccer/bundesliga/teams/1-fc-nurnberg/stats/5131",
), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
var_dump($result);
```

This is one result it prints out (It keeps going for a while longer):

```
array(6) {
    ["offset"] => int(0)["results"] => array(24) {
        [0] => array(11) {
            ["games_played"] => string(1)
            "1" ["player_name"] => string(16)
            "Patrick Rakovsky" ["goals"] => string(4)
            "1.00" ["assists"] => string(1)
            "1" ["yellow_cards"] => string(1)
            "0" ["games_started"] => string(1)
            "0" ["shots_on_goal"] => string(1)
            "4" ["fouls_suffered"] => string(1)
            "0" ["fouls_committed"] => string(1)
            "0" ["red_cards"] => string(1)
            "0" ["minutes_played"] => string(2)
            "45"
        }
```

So then I have this loop getting the "player_name" and "goals" from the result above:

```
$players = array();
foreach($result['results'] as $player){
    $players[$player['player_name']] = $player['goals'];

}
foreach($players as $player => $goals){ 

echo "Player:" . $player . "Goals:" . $goals;
}
```

I'm very new to arrays, so I know that outputs the two columns I want.. However, I want to grab and echo the rest of the results, like "assists", "yellow_cards", etc. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to grab all fields then you can assign all of $result['results'] to $player.

```
$players = $result['results']; //store all results in $players

foreach($players as $player){
    echo "Player:" . $player['player_name'] 
    . "Goals:" . $player['goals'] 
    . "Assists:" . $player['assists'];
    //access others
}
```

If you want to grab just some of the fields

```
$players = array();
$keys_to_copy = array('player_name','goals','assists'); //define fields you want to copy

foreach($result['results'] as $player){

    $player_copy = array();
    foreach($keys_to_copy as $key) {
        $player_copy[$key] = $player[$key];
    }

    $players[] = $player_copy;
}    

foreach($players as $player){
    echo "Player:" . $player['player_name'] 
    . "Goals:" . $player['goals'] 
    . "Assists:" . $player['assists'];
}
```